# Implementing Manual Checkout API in OpenCart

Tags: php, api, opencart

I am currently working on a submit order API for OpenCart. The purpose of this API is not for the webpage part of OpenCart, but for our mobile app to interact with OpenCart.

From my research, there appears to be two ways to submit an order:

**Method One:**

On the OpenCart webpage, when you want to physically want to submit an order, you go through the workflow of:

1. add product to shopping cart through `checkout/cart/add`
2. input payment_address through `checkout/payment_address/validate`
3. input shipping_address through `checkout/shipping_address/validate`
4. input shipping method through `checkout/shipping_method/validate`
5. input payment method through `checkout/payment_method/validate`
6. Confirm/submit the order through (*I don't know what URL is actually requested to submit an order*).

It appears the benefit of this method is that, given the condition that the **customer is logged in**, AND you **have an API to add items to cart**, you don't need to go through the step of manually adding products to cart in the URL. You can also use a string such as `existing` in payment_address and shipping_address to denote an existing address (so you don't need to manually input anything at all in the URL).

**Method Two:**

Using `checkout/manual`. This method, however, requires fully manually setting the inputs for everything:

1. store_id
2. customer_id
3. customer_group_id
4. payment_country_id
5. payment_zone_id
6. payment_country_id
7. order_product[]
8. order_voucher
9. shipping_method[]
10. order_total[`contains keys such as code, title, text, value, and sort_order`]
11. payment[]
12. *May have missed something..*

The use of checkout/manual seems to be the API that is for our needs, and I especially like that it would return warning/error messages if the request is not successful - however, the first method allows the the customer to have an interface to add products to cart and access existing variables such as shipping_address, payment_address, and more, given the condition that they're logged in (I'm aware that there is code that does `cart->clear()` and `customer->logout()` if the user is logged in).

My question is - has anyone ever implemented manually checking out before? How did you implement it?

**Update**:

Currently writing a script that would POST some dummy inputs to `checkout/manual`:

```
public function submit()
{
    # Our new data
    $data = array(
        "store_id" => 0,
        "customer" => "My Name",
        "customer_id" => 1,
        "customer_group_id" => 1,
        "payment_country_id" => 223,
        "payment_zone_id" => 3663,
        "order_product[0][product_id]" => 1791,
        "order_product[0][quantity]" => 1,
        "order_product[0][price]" => 5.01,
        "order_total[0][code]" => "sub_total",
        "order_total[0][title]" => "Sub-Total",
        "order_total[0][text]" => "$5.01",
        "order_total[0][value]" => 5.01,
        "order_total[0][sort_order]" => 1,
        "order_total[1][code]" => "total",
        "order_total[1][title]" => "Total",
        "order_total[1][text]" => "$5.01",
        "order_total[1][value]" => 5.01,
        "order_total[1][sort_order]" => 9,
        "payment_firstname" => "My",
        "payment_lastname" => "Name",
        "payment_company" => "SomeCompany",
        "payment_address_1" => "#123 1234 NameOf street",
        "payment_address_2" => "",
        "payment_postcode" => "12345",
        "payment_city" => "New York",
        "shipping_firstname" => "My",
        "shipping_lastname" => "Name",
        "shipping_company" => "SomeCompany",
        "shipping_address_1" => "#123 1234 NameOf street",
        "shipping_address_2" => "",
        "shipping_postcode" => "12345",
        "shipping_city" => "New York",
        "shipping" => "free.free",
        "shipping_method" => "Free Shipping",
        "shipping_code" => "free.free",
        "shipping_country_id" => 223,
        "shipping_zone_id" => 3663,
        "payment" => "cod",
        "payment_method" => "Cash On Delivery",
        "payment_code" => "cod",
        "order_status_id" => 1
    );

    # Create a connection
    $url = HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=checkout/manual';
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    # Form data string
    $postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

    # Setting our options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    # Get the response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

However, the return data is this:

`{"error":{"warning":"You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator."}}`

**Update 2**:

The error was thrown since I could not satisfy either of these conditions when callling `checkout/manual`: `$this->user->isLogged() && $this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'sale/order')`

I temporarily removed it by replace it with `true` so I can always manually add an order.

Using my input params, I do get this JSON:

`"success":"Order totals has been successfully re-calculated!"`, however, checking the administrative orders list, it does not appear a new order gets added.

**Update 3**:

Despite the ability to create the order, I don't know how to submit the order.

Comment: The only reason this very hacky, nasty method sits with the other front-end files is so that it can more easily access the totals modules, which do not exist in the back-end. It is part of the admin edit-order page (specifically, for updating totals). I would strongly recommend ignoring it and creating your own method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is dangerous to comment out the code `$this->user->isLogged() && $this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'sale/order')`.  Instead add some kind of override to the parts that reference `$this->request->post['customer_id']` so that you set the post data based on actual customer id.  If not, it would be possible for regular customers to spoof log in and checkout data as another customer simply by sending whatever `POST` data they want.

In regards to the actual order creation, you'll note that `checkout/manual` returns a json with all necessary order data.  All you need to do is add something like this after `if (!isset($json['error'])) {`

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$json['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($json);
```

Then return the json to your mobile app and show a confirmation or do whatever you want with the order data.  It might also be helpful to send a unique mobile app key along the validate whether or not the request is allowed and/or link to the appropriate customer account.